# Email I got when my bounty expired says "Your question", even though it's not

Tags: bug, bounties, email, wording

I just got an email from Stack Exchange, telling me that the grace period on my bounty had started:

> Your bounty on the question …
>
> [Cheap Wi-Fi + small mono display + a couple of buttons](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/887/cheap-wi-fi-small-mono-display-a-couple-of-buttons)
>
> … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires.
>
> Thanks for putting a bounty on *your question*. It looks like there are still no answers yet. You should consider improving *your question* to attract more answers. Could you: (...)

However, *it's not my question*. It's someone else's question which I put a bounty on.

I know this is minor, but maybe the logic should be fixed, so that the text in these emails is correct, even if the bounty is on someone else's question, and not on my own one.

Comment: Uh, just noticed that this has been asked before, closing.

Comment: No worry, happens to the best. :-)